# Reseting the position.z of a 3d object inside UseFrame

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, three.js

I am trying to build an **3d animation** w/ React and Three.js, where essentially a car starts moving forwards, therefore i decrease the value of it's **z position** in the axis using the useRef hook. When it reaches a certain point (f.e. -100) i set the state of the animation to false, the animation stops, but when i try to **reset its z position to the initial value**,it won't happen. What i noticed inside my if statement, is that even though i change the state of startCarAnimation value, the value is still true in the console. I tried changing the value by using a useEffect hook with the startCarAnimation as a dependency, but to no aveil.
Here are my **Components**. The Timer component just sets the startCarAnimation to true after certain events

**App.jsx**

```
import React , { Suspense, useState } from 'react';
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber';
import Scene from './Scene';
import Timer from './Timer';

function App() {

  const [startCarAnimation, setStartCarAnimation] = useState(false)
 

  return (
    <main >
      <Timer setStartCarAnimation={setStartCarAnimation}/>
      <Suspense fallback={null}>
          <Canvas shadows>
            <Scene startCarAnimation={startCarAnimation} setStartCarAnimation={setStartCarAnimation} />
          </Canvas>
      </Suspense>
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Scene.jsx**

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {  PerspectiveCamera } from "@react-three/drei";
import { useFrame,useLoader} from "@react-three/fiber";
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader";

export default function Scene({ startCarAnimation, setStartCarAnimation  }) {
  
  const gltf = useLoader(GLTFLoader, '../public/assets/car/scene.gltf')
  const groupRef = useRef();
  const cameraRef = useRef();
  const targetPosition = -100;
  const [zPosition, setZPosition] = useState(0);


  useFrame((state, delta) => {
    if (startCarAnimation) {
        groupRef.current.position.z = zPosition;
        setZPosition((prevScale) => Math.max(prevScale - 2, targetPosition));
        gltf.materials.tyres.map.rotation += 0.1;

        if(targetPosition == zPosition){
          setStartCarAnimation(false)
          setZPosition(0)
          console.log(startCarAnimation)
        }
        
    }
  });

  return (
    <>
      <PerspectiveCamera ref={cameraRef} makeDefault fov={30} position={[0, 0, 0.52]} />
      <group ref={groupRef}  position={[0, -0.9 , 0]} rotation={[0,Math.PI,0]} >
        <directionalLight intensity={8}  position={[0,0,1]}/>
        <ambientLight intensity={3}/>
        <primitive object={gltf.scene} />
      </group>
    </>

  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please always [read the docs](https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/api/hooks#useframe) before posting here. They explicitly tell you that `setState` calls will not work correctly within `useFrame()` hooks. You would need to stop your animation in another way

Comment: Yes, you are right, i found the solution, posting it right now

Comment: This should have been posted as a commented instead of of an answer.

Comment: Added a comment suggesting that the answer post should've been a comment since it doesn't really address the question the OP had.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the docs, which they state ''Be careful about what you do inside useFrame! You should never setState in there! '' .

```
  useFrame((state, delta) => {
    if (startCarAnimation) {
        groupRef.current.position.z -= 2;
        gltf.materials.tyres.map.rotation += 0.1;

        if(groupRef.current.position.z == targetPosition){
          groupRef.current.position.z = 0;
          setStartCarAnimation(false)
        }
    }
  });
```

i ditched the useState hook for the zPosition and just changed the position of the ref, until i reached the desired value.Then i reset the position of z and the startCarAnimation to false, to stop the animation.